# How remove specified substring and everything after it to the end of a string?

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

If I have, say, the string,

```
txt = "now is the time for all (good) men"
```

then I want to remove the substring beginning with "for" and ending at the end of the string, namely, remove:

subtext = "for all (good) men"

I do realize that an expression of the form `StringReplace[txt, regex ->""]` or  `StringReplace[txt, pattern->""]` 
will do it, but I don't know what regular expression or pattern to use.

The part of the substring to be omitted definitely begins with the specific text "for", but anything could follow it.

Comment: `StringReplace[txt, "for" ~~ ___ -> ""]`

Comment: You don't have to use a regular expression; a string expression will also work: for example, `"for" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfString`. You can see the corresponding regular expression using `StringPattern\`PatternConvert`. In this case it is `(?ms)for.*\z`.

Comment: That works. Want to make it an Answer? And do I really need the part `~~~ EndOfSting`?

Comment: @paw: Please post your comment as an answer, as it seems to supply a simpler method than using a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired replacement rule can be formulated using string expressions:

```
"for" ~~ ___-> ""
```

The pattern represents the concatenation of the string "for" with any sequence of zero or more characters.

Example:

```
txt = "now is the time for all (good) men";
StringReplace[txt, "for" ~~ ___ -> ""]
```

> ```
> "now is the time "
> ```

Answer (score 5):

This is how to do it without patterns:

```
StringDrop[
 txt,
 StringPosition[txt, "for"][[1, 1]] ;;
 ]
(* Out: "now is the time " *)
```

With patterns you have a few different options, as people have remarked in the comments. They gave you the string pattern version, this is the regular expression version:

```
StringReplace[txt, RegularExpression["for.*$"] -> ""]
(* Out: "now is the time " *)
```

where `.` denotes any character, `*` denotes zero or more times, and `$` denotes the end of the string.

(I see now that Oleksandr gave a regular expression as well, I didn't see that when I wrote the answer, but I'll let it remain.)

Comment: How get the regular expression to work in case the substring to be deleted begins with, or otherwise includes, special characters such as `(` that have special meaning in regexes? I tried the usual method of trying to escape, as `StringReplace["now is the time (for) all good men", 
 RegularExpression["\(for\).*$"] -> ""]` but that just returns the original string.

Comment: @murray You can resort to this instead: `RegularExpression["[(]for[)].*$"]` - square brackets in regex means "any of these characters" and in this case we only list one character, so it only matches that one.

Comment: Thanks for the fix to using `RegularExpression`. I'm still happier using a Wolfram Language string expression.